# PostgreSQL Unix Sockets on Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

Does anyone have a sample postgresql config for unix sockets to work on Ubuntu? It doesn't work out of the box and I can't find how to set them up.

Comment: I chmod's the dir to 0777 get around it, drwxrwsrwx 2 postgres-xc   40 Apr  7 13:00 postgresql

Comment: What does "doesn't work out of the box" mean exactly? Error message? Explosion?

Answer (score 1):

Unix domain sockets work out of the box with the postgres packages for Ubuntu.

But in your comment it appears that `postgres-xc` is the owner of the directory (as opposed to the expected `postgres`):

```
drwxrwsrwx 2 postgres-xc 40 Apr 7 13:00 postgresql
```

This is only OK if you intended to use [Postgres-XC](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Postgres-XC) which differs from PostgreSQL.

Ubuntu 14 comes with both postgresql and postgres-xc packages, and they conflict together through their dependencies:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/database/postgres-xc
http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/database/postgresql

`dpkg -l 'postgres*'` would report exactly what packages are installed on your system.

If there are unwanted `postgres-xc-*` packages, they should be uninstalled and purged, then `postgresql` installed instead, and you should be back to the standard situation.